# How to preserve the character sequence sent through SendKeys() method through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

Selenium c# when entering data in a Textbox for My Test Website the the cursor position is set to the Middle  and the data entered is like for e.g. **3421** instead of the correct Order of **1234**.

Can anyone suggest a good way as to how to handle this?

I have tried to Use pressing the HOME key button but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide what you tried so far?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: tried doing it with to enter value with JS it worked in most cases but still in some cases it enters in wrong order  ,Pressing Home key to move the cursor to first position before entering value didn't work at all, Clear+ sendKeys did not work, is there Any other way to shift the cursor Position or set value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be tough to predict the actual issue behind the non perseverance of the sequential order of the *character sequence* sent through `SendKeys()` method in absence of the relevant *HTML*.

However, in case the *AUT (Application Under Test)* is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) based, as per *best practices* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*, then you need to invoke [**`Clear()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Clear.htm) method and finally invoke `SendKeys()` method as follows:

- C#:

  ```
  IWebElement textBoxElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("xpath_of_HOME_key_button")));
  textBoxElement.Click();
  textBoxElement.Clear();
  textBoxElement.SendKeys("1234");
  ```

Comment: Tried this way but seem to be working in few cases , Is there some other way to make sure that value is always set Properly as most of our Scenarios are dependent on this Textbox being Entered Properly.

Comment: @nika65 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.