# Javascript execution for typing in text field is not behaving as sendKeys

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running my tests on Linux machine and there with following code, it does not type text correctly -

```
visibleElement.clear();
visibleElement.sendKeys("I am running on linux machine");
```

In UI, actually different text gets typed in like - "on linux machine I am running", "running on linux machine I am" etc

hence to handle this, I used javascript like -

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='I am running on linux machine';", visibleElement);
```

This types text as it is in text field, but after typing this, there is `Save` button which is expected to be enabled but that is not enabled.

But that button is enabled if `sendKeys` is used.

Could you please let me know why this javascript is behaving differently and provide correct javascript?

How both things will work in single solution(without hitting tab to enable button because that is not correct way in my situation)?

Comment: Have you tried explicit wait and `elementToBeClickable`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that for `Save` button and visually I can see that button is never enabled.

Comment: No I am talking about input field Have you tried explicit wait and `elementToBeClickable`? and then try for `sendKeys()`

Comment: Yes tried that as well but same behaviour.

Comment: Is it possible to share link if this public for diagnose.

Comment: The application I'm testing is private, cannot be accessed publicly.

Comment: You have this tagged with "javascript" but the selenium code appears to be Java.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, you're right, Selenium code is in Java but it has used javascript to perform typing text. In case if there is any better solution from javascript guys, I tagged it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write in a promise style or async/await style.

```
async clear_elem(elem) {
    // elem.clear(), MAY not work always because of some background JS
    await elem.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'a'));
    await elem.sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE);
    // Can await here for Application Load
}

reverse_string = as => as.split('').reverse().join();
// intersperse - Places an Item in between elements of an array
// ex: intersperse('k')("abc") => ['a', 'k', 'b', 'k', 'c']
intersperse = x => as => as.split('').reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, a, x], []).slice(0, -1);

(async () => {
    // Assuming you have element - visibleElement
    await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(visibleElement), default_timeout);

    await clear_elem(visibleElement);
    const str = reverse_string('I  am running on linux machine');
    const sequence_of_characters = intersperse(protractor.Key.HOME)(str);
    // e, HOME, n, HOME, i, HOME, h, HOME, ...
    await visibleElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(...sequence_of_characters));
})();
```

Comment: Tried this but did not help :(

Comment: I have edited it to click Home button for every character enter.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `arguments[0].value = "..."` sets the value on the text field, but no events are triggered on that element. The "Save" button is likely waiting for a `change` event to occur somewhere inside the `<form>`. You will need to manually trigger a change event on the text box using JavaScript. See [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2856513/3092298).

The behavior you describe makes me think JavaScript is already listening for the change event, and then scrambling the order of the words as though Yoda has typed them. (or typed them Yoda has?) Triggering the change event manually might enable the "Save" button, and you still might end up with the same text that using `sendKeys` would result in. If this is the case, you might want to enable the "Save" button with JavaScript as well:

```java
// Set the input text
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='I am running on linux machine';", visibleElement);

// Find the "Save" button
WebElement saveButton = driver.findElement(...);

// Enable the save button
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].disabled = false;", saveButton);

saveButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with element being **visible** doesn't guarantees that the element is **interactable** as well i.e **clickable** or you can straight way invoke `sendKeys()`.

To invoke `sendKeys()` within the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebElement clickableElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(visibleElement))
clickableElement.click();
clickableElement.clear();
clickableElement.sendKeys("I am running on linux machine");
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to preserve the character sequence sent through SendKeys() method through Selenium and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979535/how-to-preserve-the-character-sequence-sent-through-sendkeys-method-through-se/51979993#51979993)

---

### tl; dr

[Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)